# Some doubts about survival analysis

Tags: survival, cox-model, hazard

I'm struggling to perform a correct and unbiased survival analysis, but I  have some doubts.

### **Data**

I observe a population of posts on a blog within a temporal window $[T_{0}, T_{final}]$. Each post is characterized by:

- a $start$ date: the date in which it has been published on the blog;
- a $stop$ date: the date in which the last comment on the post has been left;
- a $event$ date: the date in which the post has been shared on Twitter for the first time.

Basically, the *lifetime* of each post is defined as the difference between $stop$ and $start$.

### **Analysis and Related Doubts**

My analysis (at least in this first part) aims at quantifying the effect on the *lifetime* of the post being shared on Twitter. Suppose I have data organized as follows:

```
id  start event stop shared
 1     0   105  192      1 
 2     0   162  245      1 
 3     0     2   88      1
```

that is, in the case of $id = 1$, the post is originally published in $t = 0$, it is shared on Twitter after $105$ weeks, and it stopped being commented after $192$ weeks. *Note that I brought back all $start$ time to zero.*

Then, I re-organized data as follows:

```
id  start stop shared event
 1     0  106      0     1
 1   106  194      1     1
 2     0  163      0     1
 2   163  247      1     1
 3     0    3      0     1
 3     3   90      1     1
```

that is, now for each id I have two rows: the first ($shared = 0$) specifies the $start$ and $stop$ times before the post is shared on Twitter; whereas the second ($shared = 1$) specifies the $start$ and $stop$ times after the post is shared on Twitter.

At this point, I would like to perform a Kaplan-Meier estimate of the survival functions *before* and *after* the post is shared on Twitter.

```
s = with(surv.df, Surv(start, stop, event))
KM = survfit(s ~ shared, data = surv.df)
```

and then apply a Cox hazard regression to model to quantify the effect on the lifetime of the post being shared on Twitter

```
sCox = coxph(s ~ as.factor(shared), data=surv.df)
summary(sCox)
```

However, I'm not convinced about such a procedure.

**Questions**

- Do you see any sources of bias in the analysis I have just presented?
- Is it correct the way I organized data to perform my analysis?
- Am I actually observing the effect of the post being shared on Twitter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found a solution to my problem. Instead of using traditional survival analysis and Cox regression models, I used multi-state models. Here two good references:

- [Multi-state models for the analysis of time-to-event data](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDUQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov%2Fpmc%2Farticles%2FPMC2692556%2F&ei=kis6VbL_OoPkONTVgPgP&usg=AFQjCNE-fQOsGWHy-7U2cnMff9zUk0_UVg&bvm=bv.91665533,d.ZWU)
- [Multi-state models: a flexible approach for modelling complex event histories in epidemiology](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC4QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsada2013.sciencesconf.org%2F16748%2Fdocument&ei=kis6VbL_OoPkONTVgPgP&usg=AFQjCNEmVzH8BVpdUWVjOWPNgyHeWQXLZA&bvm=bv.91665533,d.ZWU)

Multi-state models allow to model complex event histories, by handling censoring and left truncation, and avoiding two common kind of bias: length bias and immortal bias.

Practically, I have three states, $S = {1,2,3}$:

- $S = 1 \to$ initial state: posts are published on the blog;
- $S = 2 \to$ shared state: posts are shared on Twitter;
- $S = 3 \to$ absorbing state: posts did not receive comments in the last month;

Note that $S = 1$ is the initial state, i.e. each post starts in such a state, whereas $S = 3$ is an absorbing state, so that once the post arrives there, it remains there.

A transition matrix specifies the admissible transitions from one state to another:

$$T =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  p_{1,1}(t) & p_{1,2}(t) & p_{1,3}(t) \\
  p_{2,1}(t) & p_{2,2}(t) & p_{2,3}(t) \\
  p_{3,1}(t) & p_{3,2}(t) & p_{3,3}(t)
 \end{pmatrix}$$

In my case, I specified the following transition matrix:

$$T =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  p_{1,1}(t) & p_{1,2}(t) & p_{1,3}(t) \\
  0 & p_{2,2}(t) & p_{2,3}(t) \\
  0 & 0 & p_{3,3}(t)
 \end{pmatrix}$$

Note that all the probabilities are time-dependent. Such a transition matrix can be estimated by using R and the package [msSurv](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCkQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fweb%2Fpackages%2FmsSurv%2FmsSurv.pdf&ei=ty46VYDSBamqywOo64DYDA&usg=AFQjCNGUAO02ybNyFxpXM0KWTaUQ3EdSfA&bvm=bv.91427555,d.bGQ). Once you have estimated the transition matrix, you can analyze the state entry/exit distribution in each state, the distributions of time-varying probabilities for transitions from one state to another, and the probability to be in a given state at a certain instant $t$.

In particular, by comparing the time-varying transition probabilities $p_{1,3}(t)$ and $p_{2,3}(t)$, I can understand if there is a difference between survival times of posts being or not being shared on Twitter.